# Handling fault events

Tags: java, spring, flash, apache-flex, spring-security

Can't handle exceptions occurs on server side by flash (flex) application.

Server on java, spring-boot-web, for handling exceptions uses `org.zalando library`.

On server, for example:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = SecurityException.class)
public ResponseEntity securityViolation(Throwable e, NativeWebRequest request) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((ServletWebRequest) request).getRequest();
    ThrowableProblem problem = createBaseProblemBuilder(Error.SECURITY_ERROR, httpServletRequest)
            .withStatus(Status.FORBIDDEN)
            .withTitle("Unauthorized")
            .withDetail(e.getMessage())
            .build();
    return create(problem, request);
}

private ProblemBuilder createBaseProblemBuilder(Error error, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    return Problem.builder()
            .withType(URI.create(Error.BASE_ERROR_URL + error.getCode()))
            .with("httpMethod", httpServletRequest.getMethod())
            .withInstance(URI.create(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()))
            .with("requestTraceId", Long.toString(Thread.currentThread().getId()))
            .with("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
}
```

On client (flex):

```
public function invokeCommand(url: String, requestBody: String = null): IThenable {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill: Function = null, reject: Function = null): * {
        invokeService(requestBody, _serverInfo.serviceUrl + url,
            function (event: ResultEvent): void {
                fulfill(event.result);
            }, function (event: FaultEvent): void {
                var response: Object = event.fault.content;
                handleFault(response);
                reject(response);
            });
    });
}

private function handleFault(response: Object): void {
    var faultResponseDto: FaultResponseDto = new FaultResponseDto(response ? JSON.parse(response.toString()) : null);
    ... some code, but response already is empty
}
```

Expects, that event.fault.content contains data from server, but it always empty.
In browser network console response has payload, and contains all data from server in json.
Main question - how i can read fault payload in flash?
In debug I browse all in FaultEvent, but can't find nothing about needed data.

P.S. sorry for bad english...

Comment: `var response: Object = event.fault.content;` are you sure the response is going to be of type `Object`? Instead, does saying `var response: Object = event.data;` do anything useful?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, flashbuilder's code autocomplete says that field "content" of "fault"'s object is Object, not *, and in debug it's a String and empty (equals ""). And FaultEvent does not have field "data".
By the by, sometimes (very rarely) this fault.content has needed data, namely that server returns...

Comment: Sorry I read too fast last time and missed the `Fault` part of `Event`. Anyways.. If it works _sometimes_ then there is nothing wrong with your code. If there is _always_ a response in console then server side is okay too. How to recreate your problem easily? Are you able to provide some testable online URL that returns the expected JSON response? Then maybe we can try some methods to get that JSON from server into AS3 for you.